# DPI scaling for java app under i3

Tags: 18.04, gnome, java, hdpi

I am trying to run Xilinx Vivado on Ubuntu 18.04. Under the Ubuntu GNOME session, the application draws fine on my HiDPI display (scale of 2.) However, I would like to run i3, and running Vivado inside an i3 session results in no DPI scaling.

I'm aware of a potential [workaround](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Java_applications) for java apps, but I can't even find the jvm invocation for this particular program (they launch it from inside a compiled binary.)

I know that *something* in the GNOME session is causing the correct drawing behavior, but I'm not sure where to look. I need to find that thing and duplicate it in my i3 session.

Comment: I never found a solution, but instead worked around it by manually setting the dpi multiplier in vivado's settings